# Attempting to Deploy Flask App to AWS Beanstalk with SSL: No package mod24_ssl available

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy a Flask app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (single EC2 instance) with HTTPS enabled. I successfully deployed a version of my app without HTTPS, but then I followed this tutorial to terminate HTTPS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-python.html

Following the documentation, I created a `.ebextensions/https-instance.config` file with the template code they provide (truncated here):

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
... CERTIFICATES etc. etc. ...
```

Uploading this with my code, the deployment failed. Checking through the logs, the error was in the first part of the config file when yum attempts to install `mod24_ssl`:

`No package mod24_ssl available`

From my research (including here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222977), it seems that I may want to try installing a different package? I've attempted to replace `mod24_ssl` with `mod_ssl` or`httpd24-mod_ssl`, but both return the same error (with their respective packages "not available").

Help much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check your settings. The `mod24_ssl` is only for Amazon Linux 1. The package name for Amazon Linux 2 is `mod_ssl`. Maybe you misspell it and use `modssl` instead?

**Amazon Linux 1 (mod24_ssl)**

```
yum info mod24_ssl

Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Available Packages
Name        : mod24_ssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.4.43
Release     : 1.89.amzn1
Size        : 122 k
Repo        : amzn-updates/latest
Summary     : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The mod_ssl module provides strong cryptography for the Apache Web
            : server via the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer
            : Security (TLS) protocols.
```

**Amazon Linux 2 (mod_ssl)**

```
yum info mod_ssl

Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Available Packages
Name        : mod_ssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.4.43
Release     : 1.amzn2
Size        : 115 k
Repo        : amzn2-core/2/x86_64
Summary     : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
URL         : https://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The mod_ssl module provides strong cryptography for the Apache Web
            : server via the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer
            : Security (TLS) protocols.
```