# How do I troubleshoot 'Container commands build failed' generic error in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Problem**

I'm following this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-python.html) to enable HTTPS in my Flask Elastic Beanstalk environment. When I follow the steps outlined, I get the following error:

```
2020/08/24 21:30:04.183362 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s 
       arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:stack/awseb-e-XXXXXXXXX-stack/
       XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1 
       --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2020/08/24 21:30:04.592591 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command 
       [app-deploy] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: Container 
       commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
```

I do not have ssh access to the EC2 instances that I deployed. I'm wondering about troubleshooting this particular issue, and generally how to deal with this situation in Elastic Beanstalk.

**Question**

1. What issue might be causing the `Error: Container commands build failed` above?
2. What can I do to troubleshoot an issue like this if
   I don't have ssh access to my EC2 instance? Is there a way to view
   these `cfn-init.log` files?

**Context**

The app works perfectly if I exclude this `02_https_instance.config` file from my source code. I am wondering if the AWS example needs to be updated for Linux 2, as the `mod24_ssl` they suggest is for Linux 1, whereas I have to use `mod_ssl` in this version ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225208/attempting-to-deploy-flask-app-to-aws-beanstalk-with-ssl-no-package-mod24-ssl-a)). Are there other code updates that are required to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What issue might be causing the Error: Container commands build failed above?

[Container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) is a **section** in your `.ebextentions`. Thus it seems a commend defined in `container_commands` section failed.

> What can I do to troubleshoot an issue like this if I don't have ssh access to my EC2 instance? Is there a way to view these cfn-init.log files?

You can **download** all log files form EB console:

[image]

You have to **explicitly ask EB** to get the files using the menu on the right. By default, the logs panel will be empty if you don't ask.