# How do you restart httpd to enable HTTPS on EC2 instance in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Problem**

I am attempting to enable HTTPS on an EC2 instance in Elastic Beanstalk. I have a `https-instance.config` file in the `.ebextensions` directory which, among other things, stops and starts the `httpd` server. The original container commands are these (from the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-python.html), and also mentioned in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569357/how-do-i-troubleshoot-container-commands-build-failed-generic-error-in-aws-ela):

```
container_commands:
  01killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
  02waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

However, I get the following error, detailed in the `cfn-init.log`:

```
2020-08-25 14:51:55,622 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2020-08-25 14:51:55,631 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2020-08-25 14:51:55,634 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2020-08-25 14:51:55,638 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_tiny_app
2020-08-25 14:51:55,706 [ERROR] Command 01killhttpd (systemctl restart httpd.service) failed
2020-08-25 14:51:55,706 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_tiny_app: Command 01killhttpd failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 01killhttpd failed
2020-08-25 14:51:55,706 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2020-08-25 14:51:55,707 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01killhttpd failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 01killhttpd failed
```

I have tried removing this restart from the `https-instance.config`, and it builds but cannot connect to HTTPS. I have also attempted to replace the above commands with others to restart the `httpd` server, but these have resulted in a nearly identical error as the one above:

```
container_commands:
  01restart:
    command: "systemctl restart httpd"
```

and

```
container_commands:
  01restartservice:
    command: "systemctl restart httpd.service"
```

**Question**

How do I restart the httpd server to allow for the HTTPS connection to my app?

**Context**

- Amazon Linux 2
- Flask app in a Python 3.7 environment
- Using a single EC2 instance, so there is no load balancer
- I only need this for development purposes

Here is the full `https-instance.config` I have from AWS:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []
    
files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        
        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/application.py
        
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
          python-path=/opt/python/current/app \
          python-home=/opt/python/run/venv \
          home=/opt/python/current/app \
          user=wsgi \
          group=wsgi
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl
        
      </VirtualHost>
      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      MIID8zCCAtsCFGzyKrXOsCiyLHRPfBG75SlmQyXqMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIG1
      ...
      PuulTMAZWNXHa0g+XbRTtOQDA8FA0vlA80B+rFUQESSo2Cw5JKXTaL9OpMMG/t9S
      qvv+vGuaIw==
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

       
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA+OYzho7mXLUY6zTTqBIibsk2rfuJIO2xN2moIUNTqzJS8Yv6
      ...
      cSQsBzRR1Z5hl77Qa6gwiDx7rYswWtQt/8zsY8OUB3kg1SqriwI=
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  01restartservice:
    command: "systemctl restart httpd.service"
```

Comment: There will be a httpd restart on each fresh deployment and that is sufficient for a single EC2 instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your commands are failing is that on Amazon Linux 2
Python 3.7 environment there is **no httpd** (its physically installed, but not active). You can verify this by sshing into the instance and running:

```
sudo systemctl status httpd
```

Instead, [there are](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/python-configuration-procfile.html) `nginx` and  `gunicorn` as wsgi. The link to the AWS docs you provided is for Amazon Linux 1, not 2.

Therefore, SSL certs and HTTPs should be setup using nginx [config files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` folder.

Comment: Ok, interesting. I never would have known that from the AWS documentation--even here in their Linux 2 specific documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#ssl_enable), they talk about configuration in the '.platform/httpd/conf.d/' folder. I guess I don't know how the configuration would be different--not an expert on this--but that can be a separate question. I don't currenlty have ssh access.

Comment: @whoopscheckmate Yes. Sadly AWS docs are messy now. Some deal with Amazon Linux 1, other parts talk about Amazon Linux 2 and its not clear when they do it.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but I searched for a clear way to map the httpd configuration to the nginx configuration and didn't find anything. This is the documentation I see to enable https with nginx (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-ssl-on-nginx/) but it doesn't seem right. My question is, is there a simple way to change the config file above to do the nginx setup? If so and you're up for helping, I can ask another question. If not, should I probably contact AWS on their forums?

Comment: My one other idea was to change the wsgi to httpd somehow. Is this possible?

Comment: @whoopscheckmate Not sure at the moment. Probably you could do it, but its not clear for me now how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure AWS Linux 2 to use Apache (httpd) though it is not the default.

You can either set it via the console when creating your environment or use the following in your config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    ProxyServer: apache
```

If you are using Apache, the command to restart it is:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Also note that on AWS Linux 2, Apache is now just forwarding to localhost:8000, which is served by Gunicorn, rather than running the app via modwsgi.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60854719/2800876) for config files for self-signed certificates that work on AWS Linux 2.